# Hibnernate SQLState: 99999 , ORA-24813: cannot send or receive an unsupported LOB

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, oracle10g

Am getting an error "java.sql.SQLException: ORA-24813: cannot send or receive an unsupported LOB"

My application uses:

- [Oracle/10.2.0.1.0/jdbc/lib/ojdbc14.jar](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-10201-088211.html)
- Oracle 10.2.0.1.0.1g Database.
- Java 1.6.0_u46
- Hibernate 3

It was working , but after some time i noticed the error on search screen on the line `session.getTransaction().commit();` to close the session it raises the below erro, my query is long concatenated Strings over 1000 line after you format it in toad

```
2924554 [http-8084-3] WARN util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: 24813, SQLState: 99999
2924554 [http-8084-3] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - ORA-24813: cannot send or receive an unsupported LOB

2924554 [http-8084-3] WARN util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - SQL Error: 24813, SQLState: 99999
2924554 [http-8084-3] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - ORA-24813: cannot send or receive an unsupported LOB

2924554 [http-8084-3] ERROR def.AbstractFlushingEventListener  - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:142)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
        at hcapd.service.SearchServices.execute(SearchServices.java:3129)
        at rss.controller.CommandDispatcher.executeCommand(CommandDispatcher.java:118)
        at rss.controller.CommandControllerServlet.processRequest(CommandControllerServlet.java:34)
        at rss.controller.CommandControllerServlet.doPost(CommandControllerServlet.java:71)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at rss.filters.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at rss.filters.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at rss.filters.ValidationFilter.doFilter(ValidationFilter.java:2121)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-24813: cannot send or receive an unsupported LOB

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:343)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10656)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
        ... 34 more
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:253)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:237)
        at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:142)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:298)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1000)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:338)
        at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
        at hcapd.service.SearchServices.execute(SearchServices.java:3129)
        at rss.controller.CommandDispatcher.executeCommand(CommandDispatcher.java:118)
        at rss.controller.CommandControllerServlet.processRequest(CommandControllerServlet.java:34)
        at rss.controller.CommandControllerServlet.doPost(CommandControllerServlet.java:71)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at rss.filters.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at rss.filters.CacheFilter.doFilter(CacheFilter.java:48)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at rss.filters.ValidationFilter.doFilter(ValidationFilter.java:2121)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-24813: cannot send or receive an unsupported LOB

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:343)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10656)
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:48)
        at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:246)
        ... 34 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i solved the problem so my answer is short
by try , i replace

```
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

By

```
session.clear();
session.close();
```

And it worked and even faster but if some one knows why please edit my answer .